# Adding XeTeX to ess-swv-PDF

Tags: r, emacs, knitr, sweave, ess

I am working with an .Rnw file with Hebrew in it, and I would like to compile the resulting .tex file using XeTeX. I work in Emacs, so I am using the Emacs Speaks Statistics (ESS) package, which allows a few options for compiling the .tex file. However, using XeTeX is not currently among the possible selections of `ess-swv-PDF`, accessed via `M-n P`.

I would like to add XeTeX to this list. Ideally, this added option would allow me to not only compile the .tex file using XeTeX but also run, as needed, BibTeX on the same file—all from a buffer displaying the .Rnw file. This would be similar to `texi2pdf`, one of the current options of `ess-swv-PDF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be customized if you have ESS already installed: `M-x customize-group` select `ess-sweave` and edit `ess-swv-pdflatex-commands` to add `"xelatex"` to them. If you want to use `xelatex` or `xetex` as the default TeX engine, like I do, you can put that in front (see screenshot below).
Then press `Apply and save` this should save code into your `.init.el` or `.emacs.el`, depending on your setting.
Now when you go to your `.Rnw` file and hit `M-n P` you will see `xelatex` as default since you put it ahead of other commands. That is all to it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for! Anyway to make it run bibtex as well, as with texi2pdf?